# Java: Error trying to play a mp3 file

Tags: java, compilation, mp3

I want to play a simple mp3 file. I have this code:

```
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MelodyPlay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bip = "/Users/username/Downloads/melodytest.mp3";
        Media hit = new Media(bip);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

However, I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! uri ==...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to Media's constructor has to be a valid URI. If you want it to be a file, make it a file:// URI, like this:

`String bip = "file:///Users/username/Downloads/melodytest.mp3";`

Comment: Could you show me how to change the code? Searched around, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
file:///home/username/example.pdf
```

If you are to lazy to change your file name, just convert it:

```
(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg")));
```

So yeah, it's not really a problem with your code, just your formatting of the path.